# Bootstrap carousel is being overridden by custom css and shows all images

Tags: html, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I've tried to get Bootstrap carousel to work but the problem is that the carousel slider shows all images among each other. I can't see there is something wrong with my code, everything seems correct.

I'm working on a wordpress theme and the carousel is for a gallery post format. What I tried is, I put my custom css above the bootstrap css in the head and than carousel works fine but my custom css not working fine anymore, so I had to put my custom css above my bootstrap css again like it should be. I don't know what's wrong.

```
...
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'minimal-format-gallery' ); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header text-center">
        <?php if( minimal_get_attachment() ): 
            $attachments = minimal_get_attachment(3);
        ?> 
            <div id="post-gallery-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <?php 
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach( $attachments as $attachment ): 
                        $active = ( $i == 0 ? ' active' : '' );
                    ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item<?php echo $active; ?> background-image standard-featured" style="background-image: url( <?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); ?> );"></div>
                    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#post-gallery-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#post-gallery-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div><!-- .carousel -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your css file because you have defined a class with the same name as a bootstrap class. You should rename your custom css class or id and make sure it doesn't match with any predefined class or id. I hope after that it will work. If the problem is not resolved, edit your question and leave a comment for me.

Comment: Oh man, yes I had to rename a class, because the old class I put in had an display: block attribute and bootstrap didn't override that. Thx.